# Canvas interaction through an overlapping HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'd like to have canvas interaction through a different HTML element.

I have been using the [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) package and I added an overlapping HTML element to it. The overlapping element has no background (i.e. `background: none`) and only some text. However, the background of the overlapping element still blocks any canvas interaction.

I expect that the dots make connecting lines with the cursor both inside and outside of the box.

Here is an interaction:

[image: interaction with canvas]

Here is no interaction, where I would want it:

[image: no interaction with canvas]

A **minimum working example** can be found [here](https://codepen.io/brandsma/pen/xxEYgEM).
This example has been adapted from another [codepen](https://codepen.io/MichaelVanDenBerg/pen/WpXGRm) in order to show the problem clearly.

Is there any way to get an interaction through overlapping HTML elements?

Comment: Tell the browser to ignore pointer events on the overlapping element: `.text{pointer-events: none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As markE mentioned in the comments.

Setting `pointer-events: none` makes it possible to sent canvas interaction through an overlapping element.

*edit:* I have added the working code to the minimum working example. One only needs to uncomment it in the css.